# How to get all translations from all I18n backends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rails-i18n

I'm creating a rake task that will collect all the translations existing in the rails application and output them to file in some format (probably yaml of csv).

Is there a way to get all the translations using built-in (or in some gem) methods?

Currently, the best I could think of is iterating over `I18n.backend.backends` check their class and based on that perform different actions and in the end merge everything into a single hash.

Something like

```
all_translations = {}
I18n.backend.backends.each do |backend|
  if backend.class == Simple
    translations = backend.send(:translations)
    # etc
  elsif backend.class == KeyValue
    # something else
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all backends conform to the same interface (which in my opinion is pretty horrible), however you can accomplish what you need to through either monkey-patching or creating your own backend that is based off of one of the built-in I18n backends.

For example, I wanted to have a redis backend that falls back to default rails I18n backend, and I needed it to work with the i18n-js gem.  Since the KeyValue backend allows you to look up translations for an entire subtree, it is possible then to simulate a "translations" method as long as you store everything under a top level key.  It's as simple as doing: **backend.translate(:en, 'top-level-key')"**

```
# config/initializers/custom_i18n.js
module CustomI18n
  def self.backend
    Backend::Chain.new
  end

  module Backend
    class Chain < I18n::Backend::Chain
      def initialize
        super(RedisStore.new, I18n::Backend::Simple.new)
      end

      def initialized?
        backends.all? do |backend|
          !backend.respond_to?(:initialized?) || backend.initialized?
        end
      end

      protected

      def translations
        backends.each_with_object({}) do |backend, hash|
          backend.instance_eval do
            if respond_to?(:translations, true)
              hash.deep_merge! translations
            else
              available_locales.each do |locale|
                translations = translate(locale, RedisStore::SCOPE, :scope => nil) rescue ArgumentError
                hash.deep_merge!({ locale => translations }) if translations
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end

    class RedisStore < I18n::Backend::KeyValue
      SCOPE = 'redis'

      def initialize(*args)
        super(Redis.new)
      end

      def translate(*args)
        args << {} unless args.last.is_a?(Hash)
        args.last[:scope] = SCOPE unless args.last.has_key?(:scope)
        super
      end

      def store_translations(locale, data, options = {})
        super(locale, { SCOPE => data }, options)
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.backend = CustomI18n.backend
```

So, with this approach, you can do something like:

```
redis_backend = I18n.backend.backends.find { |backend| backend.is_a?(CustomI18n::Backend::RedisStore) }
redis_backend.store_translations(:en, {:foo => { :bar => { :baz => 'qux' } } })
```

And that automatically gets stored under the top level key of "redis", but you can access it normally a variety of different ways:

```
> I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en][:foo]
=> {:bar=>{:baz=>"qux"}}

> I18n.t('foo')
I18N keys: [:en, :foo]
 => {:bar=>{:baz=>"qux"}}
```

but if you actually look at redis, you can see it's stored under the top level key:

```
> Redis.new.get('en.redis')
 => "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":{\"baz\":\"qux\"}}}"
```